# Why am I encountering a 403 and a 502 error when deploying my Angular Project to S3?

Tags: angular, entity-framework, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to deploy an Angular project that accesses a .NET Core Web API to S3. I have deployed my Web API to Lambda, and am able to play around with it when I run the Angular project locally. However, when I deploy it to S3, my page shows `{"message": "Internal server error"}`. The console shows the following errors:

- `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()`
- `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 ()`

As mentioned earlier, I have tried running the Angular project locally, using the url that was generated when I deployed to Lambda. I am able to execute all the REST APIs and my project works as expected. I encountered similar issues while simply deploying my .NET Core project to Lambda, but found that the issue was that I had not set the permissions for the Lambda properly. I expect the issue here to be of the same nature, but am not sure where to start.

My `serverless.yml` file looks like this:

```
# generated by @ng-toolkit/serverless
service: [service-name]

plugins:
  - serverless-apigw-binary

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  memorySize: 192
  timeout: 10
  stage: production
  region: us-east-1

package:
  exclude:
   - src/**
   - node_modules/**
   - firebug-lite/**
   - e2e/**
   - coverage/**
   - '!node_modules/aws-serverless-express/**'
   - '!node_modules/binary-case/**'
   - '!node_modules/type-is/**'
   - '!node_modules/media-typer/**'
   - '!node_modules/mime-types/**'
   - '!node_modules/mime-db/**'

custom:
  apigwBinary:
    types:
      - '*/*'

functions:
  api:
    handler: lambda.universal
    events:
      - http: ANY {proxy+}
      - http: ANY /
```

My `proxy.conf.json` file looks like this:

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target":"[Lambda URL]/dev/api/",
        "secure":false,
        "changeOrigin":true 
    }
}
```

Please let me know if any other code needs to be added to diagnose the problem. I am not adding any of my .NET Core code or any of the actual HTML/Typescript code, as I don't currently think these affect the problem at hand. However, if these are needed, I will provide some excerpts.

The expected output should be a simple HTML page that displays a simple input form for Students (with First Name, Last Name, and some other details). Along with this, there is a list containing all the Students already in the database. Clicking on these will populate the form with the details of that particular student.

This is exactly what is produced when i simply run `ng serve --open`. The errors only occur when I run `npm run build:serverless:deploy`

Answer (score 2):

You may be having an issue with the "stage" path that gets appended to your URL in API Gateway. (ie: /production/)

The standard suggestion is to register a custom domain for your API gateway, but you could also try modifying your projects index to a different path.

See this article (ctrl+f 403) for more information: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/09/serverless-deploy-nodejs-application-on-faas-without-pain.html